# How to programatically grant "Log on as a service" to a virtual account

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I'm following this guide on using virtual accounts for Windows services:  https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd548356%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Accordingly, these types of accounts are not manually created but simply used implicitly.  This guide does not mention it, but it's also required to grant the "Log on as a service" right to the non-existent virtual accounts.

For example, SQL Server Express 2014 uses virtual accounts for its services and runs them as a user much like `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`.  Once installed, you can find the account names in the "Log on as a service" account listing.

The problem is that I am not sure how to programmatically grant this right to a virtual account.  I've looked at using the `LsaAddAccountRights` function using pinvoke but it requires specifying the SID of the account.  I do not believe that a virtual account *has* an SID.

How can I grant logon as a service rights to a virtual account, the way Microsoft does with SQL Server Express?

Comment: Not an answer but - _"The Database Engine runs in Windows as a Windows service named MSSQLSERVER. The NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER login is used by the service to connect to the Database Engine. Basically, this is how it connects to itself ... they [this and the Agent account] can't be selected in the list of available built-in accounts, local accounts or domain accounts because they are services, not accounts. They have a security identifier (SID) in Windows, but Windows knows they aren't real users. Windows can authenticate them, but they don't have passwords that any human can use."_

Comment: ^^ from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e6bb2de-8fd0-45de-ab02-d59bbe05f72e/servicedatabase-accounts-nt-servicemssqlserver-nt-servicesqlserveragent-what-are-they-for?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: A better explanation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Specifically, it's specified as using a "Virtual Account" when installed with Win7/Server 2008 R2 or higher.  The problem is that it seems virtual accounts do not seem to have an SID until they are used for the first time, and I can't use them without granting Log on as a service privilege, which I can't do without an SID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the "log on as a service" right is granted to `ALL SERVICES` so as your self-answer says you don't need to add each service explicitly.  However, you might need to do so if the configuration has been modified.  (That's presumably why the SQL installer does so.)

Virtual service accounts *do* have SIDs, which have a 1:1 correspondence with the service name.  There is even a command line tool that can calculate them in advance if you need to:

```
C:\>sc showsid xyzzy

NAME: xyzzy
SERVICE SID: S-1-5-80-1601682549-2674398373-2289982826-1892655095-2161370298
```

I can't find an API to do this calculation in advance, once you have installed the service (note that the logon right is only needed in order for the service to start successfully, not in order to install it) you can look up the SID in the same way you would look up any other SID, e.g., LookupAccountName().

Comment: Brilliant.  An API shouldn't be needed, because it's not a machine-specific SID.  For example, a service named MyService will always be SID `S-1-5-80-517257762-1253276234-605902578-3995580692-1133959824` on all machines.  So I can probably hardcode the SID.

Comment: However, I've been trying to grant the Log on as a service right to a SID manually using LsaAddAccountRights, using the SID generated above, but it doesn't seem to work.  It adds it to the list of users with the Log on as a service right, but doesn't resolve the SID to the name "NT Service\ServiceName" and it fails to actually log in a service.

Comment: @TrevorElliott: um.  Well, it won't resolve the name until the service is installed, and even once that is done you might need to restart the management console (or perhaps even the entire system) to see it.  So that part might be OK, but I don't know why the service would fail to start.  The service manager should have recorded the error code in the event log, perhaps that will give us a clue?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, virtual service accounts do not explicitly need the "Log on as a service" right granted.

The problem was that the logon name had to match the exact name of the service for which it was used.  So for a service named MyService, the logon name had to be exactly "NT Service\MyService".  It can't be an arbitrary account name.

EDIT:

Technically, they do need "Log on as a service" permission, but this is granted by default as the `NT Service\ALL SERVICES` right.  It's possible that this permission might have been modified by the user however.

Comment: I made the same mistake when configuring Tomcat. The service name is `Tomcat8` and I wrongly assumed I couldn't use a digit when setting the logon name, but it turns out `NT Service\Tomcat8` works fine.